# Bypass softlockup_threshold

Tags: c, linux, module, linux-kernel, kernel

I develop a kernel module which does a heavy job which of course takes time.
The problem is that the module utilizes the CPU for more than 20 seconds and as 
a result a BUG of softlockup_threshold is raised.

My question is, is there any way to bypass this? i.e. can it tamper the threshold?
Or can it force scheduling and continue its work later? (in order to set the timer to 0).

Thank you in advance,
Panos

Comment: Offload the hard work to a user process, talking to the kernel module via a special device. You should really not do heavy calculations in a kernel!

Comment: I can't :( I am brute forcing the VM of the kernel in order to detect hidden kenrel modules. It has to be done in kernel space.

Comment: you could try to yield for a while

Comment: Use cond_resched() in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to yield the CPU for a while, If that's acceptable, then you should look into `schedule()` There's a great article here about [Sleeping in the Kernel](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8144)

Comment: Thanks! If it's not? because i.e. I want my module to be unscheduled and non interrupted?

Thanks again fo the help,
Panos

Comment: @Panos I'm sorry, the correct call is `schedule()` `sched_yield()` is system call, I've also added a link to the answer you should have a look.

Answer (score 3):

With new kernels, you can tune /proc/sys/kernel/watchdog_thresh (Older kernels use /proc/sys/kernel/softlockup_thresh, I think). But this is not encouraged, because blocking for 20 seconds means there is some problem with you code, you should yield the CPU, e.g. by calling cond_resched().